# Get android mobile token for Push notifications

Tags: php, android, devicetoken

I have a android application which sends to my PHP script the following information:
mobile_id, os_version, app_version.

Is it possible to retrieve the android device token
from those parameters? I've heard you should connect to google somehow to get it..

But, I couldn't find any information about..

I'm newbie to android applications. any help will be appreciated:)

Comment: Why do you need android device token? Your application would be only for Android or for other platforms as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement GCM to do so.

Please follow this link for details explanations.

[Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GCM is being deprecated.  Use FCM instead:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Same platform as GCM but extended with more features.